# How do I save the string data I have extracted from several excel sheets to a new workbook using openpyxl / pandas or anything python?

Tags: python, excel, string, openpyxl

Second question to the Stack overflow community - I'm not great at this yet....

I am trying to write some code that will

1. open a series of excel documents and locate the sheet 'Moderated'
2. extract values from a number of cells
3. rearrange the data into a new excel sheet with each individual spreadsheet being represented as a new row of cells

I THINK that I have achieved 1 and 2 of the list above - although the values are returned as a string and this seems to be causing issues with saving to excel. The sloppy import code section reflects the options I have explored so far...

```
`import sys
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
from openpyxl.workbook import workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path=r'C:\Users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox' #working directory
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")#lists all excel files

for file in filenames:
    
    wb1 = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)#works
    ws1=wb1['Moderated']#works
    
    for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=3,max_row=7,min_col=5,max_col=5):
        for cell in row:
            a=(cell.value)
            print (a) #works
            
   
    for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=3,max_row=7,min_col=7,max_col=7):
        for cell in row:
            b=(cell.value)
            print (b) 

print(type(a))
    
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox\Out\Out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df.to_excel(writer, index=True)`
```

Output so far...
Sheet 1 text1 (e2)
Sheet 1 text2 (e4)
Sheet 1 text3 (e5)
None
Sheet 1 text4 (e7)
Sheet 1 text5 (g3)
Sheet 1 text6 (g4)
Sheet 1 text7 (g5)
Sheet 1 text 8 (g6)
Sheet 1 text9 (g7)
sheet 2 text1 (e2)
sheet 2 text2 (e4)
sheet 2 text3 (e5)
None
sheet 2 text4 (e7)
sheet 2 text5 (g3) 
sheet 2 text6 (g4)
sheet 2 text7 (g5)
Sheet 2 text 8 (g6)
sheet 2 text9 (g7)
<class 'str'>

What I would like to have eventually is..
[image: excel sheet with 10 columns all in a different order from the original list recover, one per spreadsheet read]

ANY help would be appreciated - but especially if aimed at newbie programmer

---

THANK YOU to JONAS for suggesting code below - output now looks like this
[image: screenshot of excel spreadsheet with 5 column headers and 4 rows]
5 columns rather than the 9 I was aiming for.  I also want to title the headings differently, so H1 / HA / Header A is just a bookmark, I wasnt clear about that when I first asked the question

[image: excel spreadsheet with 10 column headings and 2 rows]

Jonas - your your code MUCH better than my code [much more elegant!]

---

With the suggested code

---

```
#LATEST
import sys
import os
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
from openpyxl.workbook import workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import writer

path=r'C:\Users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox' #working directory
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")#lists all excel files

new_df=[] #create new DataFrame

#create a new list, which will be your result

for file in filenames:
    
    wb1 = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)#works
    ws1=wb1['Moderated']#works
    
    a = [] #list for values in col = 5
    b = [] #list for values in col = 7

    for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=3,max_row=7,min_col=5,max_col=7): #use the loop to directly get the values from column 5 and 7.
        for i, cell in enumerate(row):
            if i == 0: a.append(cell.value) # save cell of col = 5 value into list a
            if i == 2: b.append(cell.value) # save cell of col = 7 value into list b

    new_df.append(a+b) #append list a and b to your bigger list for each excel-fi              
                
import string   
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase[:27] # Alphabet for column names (header A, header B, ...)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(new_df, columns = ['header ' + alphabet[i] for i in range(len(new_df[0]))]) #create new DataFrame

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox\out\out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

wb.save(r'C:\users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox\out\out.xlsx') 

print('Spreadsheet saved')#works
```

ERROR CODE: NameError: name 'wb' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you could try is to save the values of your cells into a `list` and then again save this list into a `list` for each of your excel-files, which will be your new `DataFrame`:

```
new_df = [] #create a new list, which will be your result

for file in filenames:
    
    wb1 = load_workbook(file, data_only=True)#works
    ws1=wb1['Moderated']#works
    
    a = [] #list for values in col = 5
    b = [] #list for values in col = 7

    for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=3,max_row=7,min_col=5,max_col=7): #use the loop to directly get the values from column 5 and 7.
        for i, cell in enumerate(row):
            if i == 0: a.append(cell.value) # save cell of col = 5 value into list a
            if i == 2: b.append(cell.value) # save cell of col = 7 value into list b

    new_df.append(a+b) #append list a and b to your bigger list for each excel-file    


import string   
alphabet = string.ascii_uppercase[:27] # Alphabet for column names (header A, header B, ...)
    
df = pd.DataFrame(new_df, columns = ['header ' + alphabet[i] for i in range(len(new_df[0]))]) #create new DataFrame

with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox\Out\Out.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer)
```

Comment: that is looking so much better - but the output is on 5 columns not the 9 I was aiming for

Comment: You can vary the range of rows and columns in the inner for-loop. Currently you are getting the values from min_row = 3 to max_row = 7 for the columns 5 and 7. If you want to get more rows, change these values (min_row / max_row) to whatever you like.

Comment: I might not have been clear... the loop is working great - picking up all the right cells.... It's that the output to excel is in 5 columns and twice as many rows as there are spreadsheets.  I wanted one row per spreadsheet - and I just can't seem to get there! #frustration!

Comment: Well in this case you can just change "new_df.append(a)" and "new_df.append(b)" to "new_df.append(a+b)" (I edited it in my post).

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for your help - I think it's there but I have managed to accidentally delete the excel export lines that previously worked.#FACEDESK

Comment: Happy to help. I edited the export code in my post above. Feel free to mark the answer as correct, so it can be helpful to others, too.

Comment: THANKS for much for all your help. Sorry for the late reply - I put a print("saved") at the end - and that is appearing, but the file is not saving - the directory remains stubbornly empty :(

Comment: writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox\out\out.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
#does not create a workbook in the directory above

#wb.save(r'C:\users\longr\Desktop\pfile\sandbox\out\out.xlsx') creates a blank file, no workbook

print('Spreadsheet saved')#works

Comment: I tried the append you created on a clean Jupyter notebook. [NameError: name 'wb' is not defined]

Comment: Hm, in the code above is no variable called "wb", but "wb1". Did you change something?

Comment: faffed with it - got a new unicode error - so added in 'r' to the file name (r'C:\user ...and it WORKS!! THANK YOU ! all should be voted 'answered'' - helpful etc - PLEASE let me know if I can buy you a beer! :D